# Translate from routes.rb Ruby to urls.py Django

Tags: ruby, django, hirefire

I need to modify the file urls.py with a static url.
The next line is coded in Ruby Lang in routes.rb

```
match "/hirefire/#{ENV["HIREFIRE_TOKEN"]}/info" => "hire_fire#info"
```

I don't know how to code the same line in urls.py Django.
Please I need your help.